# Why is there a tenfold difference between Postgres's alleged query execution time and the client getting it?

Tags: database, postgresql, networking

I've been pulling my hair out over this for days now, as I'm trying to build a low latency application.  Databases should be fast, but I can not work out why so much latency is added between the actual database process and the application code.  For simple queries, that should take less than a millisecond this mystery latency is by far the biggest performance hit.

For example, I have a very simple table on a local Postgres database, which takes 324us.  This is absolutely fine.

```
postgres=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS OFF, TIMING OFF)
 select count("ID") from example t;
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------------------------------------------------
QUERY PLAN | Aggregate (actual rows=1 loops=1)
-[ RECORD 2 ]------------------------------------------------------
QUERY PLAN |   ->  Seq Scan on example t (actual rows=4119 loops=1)
-[ RECORD 3 ]------------------------------------------------------
QUERY PLAN | Planning Time: 0.051 ms
-[ RECORD 4 ]------------------------------------------------------
QUERY PLAN | Execution Time: 0.324 ms
```

But then if I want to connect to the database in Python, getting the actual data takes over 2500us!  The loopback interface is not the problem here, I sanity checked that (it adds 100us at a stretch).

```
In [1]: %time cursor.execute("select count(\"ID\") from example;");r = cursor.fetchmany()
CPU times: user 316 µs, sys: 1.12 ms, total: 1.44 ms
Wall time: 2.73 ms
```

Investigating further, I opened up WireShark to see how long the packets themselves take.

[image: Wireshark screenshot]

From this I can tell that Postgres took 2594us to send the data.  This kind of overhead for an loopback IPC call is way beyond what I would expect. Why is this? And how can I optimise this away?

This is a problem for the software ecosystem, because people start thinking databases are too slow to do simple lookups, and they start caching queries in Redis that take 300us to execute, but 3ms to actually fetch back to the client.

Comment: I have no such problem in python, perl, or C.  I would suggest the problem is in your client, which looks kind of like, but not exactly, python.

Comment: My client is python.

Comment: What kind of performance are you getting?

Comment: @Rol also paste your python code

Comment: It’s literally in the Ipython prompt. The only thing that’s missing is creating the cursor and connection, which are done completely normally.

Comment: maybe add your connection

Comment: Conn = Psycopg2.connection(‘localhost’, ‘password’)

Comment: %time doesn't do anything useful for me in python.  I get 2.5 to 4.5 second for 10000 loops of execute and fetchmany, which works out to 0.25 to 0.45 ms.  So about 10x faster.

Comment: @jjanes you need to use ipython to use it. It’s just a little REPL wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried a similar experiment on my machine, measuring the time with `psql`'s `\timimg`.

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` showed similar times, but the actual time measured from the client took around 0.85 ms via loopback interface and 0.6 ms via Unix sockets.

That confirms the overhead of around 0.1 ms for using the loopback interface, but it shows a marked difference otherwise.

Here are some ideas:

- perhaps your measurement is off, although I cannot imagine how Wireshark could get it wrong
- perhaps there is some problem with the loopback interface on your machine, although I know too little about networking to say what
- perhaps you didn't repeat the measurements often enough, since I observe that the first call on a new connection always takes somewhat longer